az cli to create an apim named value that references a key vault secret
I'd like to use az cli to create an apim named value that references a key vault secret.
It seems this is not supported natively: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/27822
I've tried the work-around using az rest but no luck so far.
From my script
$ApiUrl = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/$apimServiceName/namedValues/${namedValueName}?api-version=2023-09-01-preview"
Write-Host $ApiUrl
Write-Host $NamedValueProperties

# Use az rest command to invoke Azure REST API for creating/updating the named value
$response = az rest --method put --url $ApiUrl --body $namedValuePropertiesString --headers "Content-Type=application/json" --output json | ConvertFrom-Json

# Output the response status code and body for diagnosis
Write-Host $response.properties

The output
$ApiUrl = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/$apimServiceName/namedValues/${namedValueName}?api-version=2023-09-01-preview" Write-Host $ApiUrl Write-Host $NamedValueProperties
    
# Use az rest command to invoke Azure REST API for creating/updating the named value $response = az rest --method put --url $ApiUrl --body $namedValuePropertiesString --headers "Content-Type=application/json"
--output json | ConvertFrom-Json
    
# Output the response status code and body for diagnosis Write-Host $response.properties https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/sub-id/resourceGroups/rg/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apim-name/namedValues/nv-name?api-version=2023-09-01-preview {
"properties":  
{
    "keyVault":  {
                    "identityClientId":  "client-id",
                    "secretIdentifier":  "https://kv-name.vault.azure.net/secrets/SecretThing"
                },
    "displayName":  "nv-name",
    "secret":  true
} } @{ProvisioningState=InProgress}

So, it runs without error but the "ProvisioningState" never progress beyond "InProgress" and I don't see the new named value appear in the Azure portal (or by querying with az cli).

APIM takes a very long time to be provisioned. I think you need to wait until it's ready, before trying to do the rest.

The apim instance exists already; I'm just trying to add a named value to it.

If using Portal also for deploying API Management service, it takes very long time. Have you tried using Portal by any chance? @RobBowman

The apim instance exists already; I'm just trying to add a named value to it.

The example body from the Github issue is incorrect:

{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "$namedValue",
    "secret": true,
    "keyVault": {
      "identityClient": "$managedIdentityClientId",
      "secretIdentifier": "$keyVaultSecretUri"
    }
  }
}

Based on the Microsoft Documentation the follow body is correct:
{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "prop6namekv",
    "secret": true,
    "keyVault": {
      "identityClientId": "ceaa6b06-c00f-43ef-99ac-f53d1fe876a0",
      "secretIdentifier": "https://contoso.vault.azure.net/secrets/aadSecret"
    }
  }
}

The issue is the name of the json-property.
False:
identityClient
Correct:
identityClientId

thanks for the answer Markus but I was already using identityClientId - as shown in "The Output" section of my question

Apologies for the confusion in the GitHub issue. I referred to the correct approach in the original issue but mistakenly provided the incorrect JSON in the later comment.
I have updated to correct this now in the issue.
